# Clojure normalize function runtime error

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

This code that I wrote gives me the error:

```
java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

which means that I am using a number where a function is expected.

I think it has to do with the expt functions from clojure.math.numeric-tower but I am not sure. cryptic error messages FTL.

```
(ns point-normalize.core
  (:require [clojure.math.numeric-tower :as math :only (sqrt expt)]))

(defn normalize [x y]
  (let [x1 (/ x (math/sqrt ((math/expt x 2)+ (math/expt y 2))))
        y1 (/ y (math/sqrt ((math/expt x 2)+ (math/expt y 2))))]
    (x1 y1)))
```

Any hints would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the + is in the wrong place in:

```
((math/expt x 2)+ (math/expt y 2)))
```

should be:

```
(+ (math/expt x 2) (math/expt y 2)))
```

and the same for y1 as well. Since you have this correct elsewhere it looks like a simple typo.

While it's very normal to see `)))))))` in clojure code, occurrences of `((` warrent a second glance.

Comment: Oh my god...I was just programming in C++ so thats why. thank you!